# DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, dbms-scheduler

I added `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB`.

```
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
(
   job_name        => 'CHECK'
  ,start_date      => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2000/12/26 01:00:00.000000 +00:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss.ff tzh:tzm')
  ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYMINUTE=05'
  ,end_date        => NULL
  ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
  ,job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
  ,job_action      => 'begin check.Checkname() end;'
  ,enabled         => TRUE
  ,comments        => ''
);
```

In `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS` I am getting the job details but Its in `SCHEDULED` State.

Its not running. When I tired to run the job manually its throwing some error.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: "... its throwing some error". Stupid errors. I wonder what it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But that's correct !

With your `start_date` and `repeat_interval` settings you run the job once every day at `01:05`.

```
JOB_NAME START_DATE                             REPEAT_INTERVAL        STATE     NEXT_RUN_DATE
-------- -------------------------------------- ---------------------- --------- -------------------------------------- 
LOGGER2  26-DEC-00 01.00.00.000000000 AM +00:00 FREQ=DAILY;BYMINUTE=05 SCHEDULED 19-SEP-13 01.05.00.600000000 AM +00:00
```

if you want to run the job every 5 minutes use:

```
start_date => systimestamp,
repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=5'

JOB_NAME START_DATE                             REPEAT_INTERVAL          STATE     NEXT_RUN_DATE
-------- -------------------------------------- ------------------------ --------- -------------------------------------- 
LOGGER3  18-SEP-13 06.53.53.532906000 PM +00:00 FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=5 SCHEDULED 18-SEP-13 06.58.53.500000000 PM +00:00
```